# jQuery div clickable and follow child URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can somebody please explain to me why this doesn't work?

I'm sorry I'm a total starter on javascript + jQuery.

Here's the code:

**Javascript / jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.clickk').click(function(e){
        window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div  class="clickk" >
    <a href="google.com">link</a>
    blah blah blah.
 </div>
```

Please help me find what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance. Hoping the question is clear.

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? Normally the link would work just fine. Did you try putting the code in the ready event?

Comment: simple ! when i click the div it should follow the anchor element inside thus in this case go to google.com.

Comment: Try putting it in the ready event (as many suggest below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two probable issues:

1. You're probably executing that script before any elements with that class exist in the DOM (more below).
2. The `href` should start with `http://`, e.g., `href="http://www.google.com"` or `href="http://google.com"`. Just `href="google.com"` makes it a *relative* link, which won't work reliably.

Assuming you fix #2, here's some detail on #1:

Won't work:

```
<!-- ... -->
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('.clickk').click(function(e){
     window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<div  class="clickk" >
   <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
   blah blah blah.
</div>
```

There are two ways to fix this:

### Put the script at the end of the page

This is usually the preferred way, put your scripts at the *end* of the page, not the beginning.

Works:

```
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<div  class="clickk" >
   <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
   blah blah blah.
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('.clickk').click(function(e){
     window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  });
</script>
</body>
```

This also reduces apparent page load time by not holding up rendering while waiting for the scripts to download. See [YUI's guidelines](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) (or any of several others). DOM elements defined *above* a script are accessible to that script. DOM elements defined *below* the script are not (unless you do something like the following to delay things).

### Use the `ready` event

If for some reason putting the scripts at the end doesn't suit, you can use the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) event:

Works:

```
<!-- ... -->
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  jQuery(function($) {
      $('.clickk').click(function(e){
         window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
      });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<div  class="clickk" >
   <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
   blah blah blah.
</div>
```

Note that passing a function into `jQuery` (or into `$`, which is just an alias for `jQuery` unless you use `noConflict`) is the same as passing one into `$(document).ready(...)`; details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Comment: very great answer. thank you. exactly my mistake. sorry cant vote.. only 1 rep :# hehe

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.clickk').click(function(e){
        window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');}
    });
)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 href="google.com" // This is a relative url
```

try

```
href="http://www.google.com/"  // Instead
```

Also  encase it in DOM ready event.. Maybe the script was executed even before the elements were in the DOM .. This makes sure events are attached after the elements are available in the DOM..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(function() {
    $('.clickk').click(function(e){
       window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    });
  });
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CAxBr/)

Comment: oh thank you ... but what is the difference between this and  $("document").ready(fucntion() ?

Comment: Both are the same.. This is just the shortform of $("document").ready(fucntion()

Answer (score 0):

try this

**use  the ready event**

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clickk').click(function(e){
       window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Of course when you add  `$(function() {` to his code, then he is missing `})`

Answer (score -1):

Just adding my two bits.
You can use the following code. Although the answer given by others should also work for you (Personally I didn't like the idea of using  window.location.href :) )

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.clickk').click(function(e){
     $(this).find('a')[0].click();
  });
  });
</script>


<div  class="clickk" style="cursor:pointer">
   <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
   blah blah blah.
 </div>?
```

Comment: :) @ downvoter There wasn't a need to downvote.. doesnt the code work? or didnt I mention that I was just adding my two bits??.. you could have pointed out what you didn't like!..

Comment: FWIW, "Just adding my two bits" sounds like it should be a *comment*, not an *answer*. Your answer doesn't actually answer the question, it suggests a different way to do something unrelated to the issue with the code in the question. Also, I wouldn't rely on the undocumented behavior of calling `click` on an anchor element following the link instead of the well-supported behavior of the `location` object. But other than that... :-)

Comment: yeah that's more like it.! :)